# PC beeps repeatedly in short groups of 3, never POSTs

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

I have an HTPC that I built back in September of 2013 with the following specs:

- CPU: [Intel i3-3245](http://ark.intel.com/products/74746/Intel-Core-i3-3245-Processor-3M-Cache-3_40-GHz)
- Motherboard: [ASRock H77M](http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.us.asp?Model=H77M&cat=Specifications)
- Case: [LIAN LI PC-C50B](http://www.lian-li.com/en/dt_portfolio/pc-c50/)
- Power Supply: [OCZ ModXStream Pro 500W](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=17-341-016)
- RAM: [Kingston HyperX XMP Blu Red Series 8GB](http://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search/Default.aspx?DisPartId=KHX16C9B1RK2/8X)
- Hard disk: [SAMSUNG 840 MZ-7TD120BW](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/MZ-7TD120BW)
- Optical: [Pioneer BDR-208DBK](http://www.pioneerelectronics.com/PUSA/Computer/Computer+Drives/BDR-208DBK)
- Keyboard: [Logitech K400](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400r)
- OS: Windows 7 x64

Overall it's been a decent living room PC and ran fine up until last night. I couldn't get it to wake up so I hard reset it and now I get a series of 3 short beeps, followed by 3 short beeps, then the power light blinks and this continues forever.

Here is a very short video of the issue:
https://vine.co/v/Oqpx32lTqni

I've tried:

- cleaning all the dust out of the PC, fans, heatsinks, grills
- pulling the RAM and booting (this would cause 3 long beeps)
- trying the RAM in different slots, one at a time
- clearing the CMOS
- connecting a PS2 keyboard
- disconnecting HDMI and using DVI
- disconnecting DVI and using VGA

I haven't found many similar cases of these beep codes, most people seem to be getting the 3 long beeps for RAM errors. [According to biosflash.com](http://www.biosflash.com/e/bios-beeps.htm#AMI) these short beeps could be one of the following:

- 3x short beeps:  Base 64K RAM failure
- 6x short beeps:  Keyboard controller Gate A20 error

Unfortunately I don't know what either of those would be caused by. I'm leaning towards motherboard, but I suppose it could possibly be RAM or CPU too. I think I have some different RAM that will work so I'm going to try that tonight. I don't have a spare LGA1155 CPU.

I've tried to contact ASRock support but haven't heard from them yet and don't expect them to be all that helpful.

Does anyone have a better idea what it might be? Or run into this before?

Comment: 3 short beeps would be the CPU;  6 short beeps would be the motherboard.  If the hardware is under warranty I would go that route, do both the CPU and motherboard, that way your covered.

Comment: @Ramhound where is that info from? I couldn't find anything helpful about these beep-codes on ASRock's site

Comment: Where is this information from?  17 years dealing with computers.  The 64K RAM is the Cache on the CPU and the keyboard controller would be on the motherboard..

Comment: @Ramhound ah ok, I thought maybe you've had experience with this motherboard firsthand with the same issue. (or found someone else who has)

Comment: A motherboard is a motherboard.  **You deal with one you have basically seen them all.**  You wanted help I provided my  thoughts based on my significant amount of experience.

Comment: I'm not sure why my questions appear to upset you, that was not my intention. I actually have found someone with the same motherboard and an identical issue: http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/2dmigp/pc_wont_boot_3_short_beeps_followed_by_3_more/clas8do

Comment: I am not upset;  But...I sort of feel like you threw my response aside because I specifically wasn't familiar with this motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ramhound was right, after going through very basic troubleshooting with ASRock, they RMA'd it. I got the replacement in last week and it's been running for a few days now without any issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, the same beeps. Only one DDR3 of 4GB. I will come back with a comment when I finish the investigation.

Comment: @AndreiRinea if it's under warranty you should contact the manufacturer for a replacement. I've had no issues since.